# Assume a role before generating presgined s3 url

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-macie

In our django application, we allow users to upload files directly to S3.

We do this using [generate_presigned_post](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_post).

All works great, but we now get Suspicious Access alerts in [Macie](https://aws.amazon.com/macie/) because it sees that EC2 credentials are being used externally.

The Macie description is

> This alert is created by temporary EC2 instance credentials being used
>   outside of Amazon IP space. EC2 instance profile credentials are
>   expected to most commonly be used on EC2 instances where they have
>   been made available by the EC2 metadata service. This technique is
>   used by open source exploitation frameworks such as Metasploit, and
>   observing their usage from outside of AWS network may indicate their
>   potential leakage. Please consider reaching out to user to confirm
>   whether they were intentially using EC2 credentials outside of AWS. If
>   so, whitelist valid users or consider resetting IAM user credentials.

This makes sense because the Instance role generates the presigned post url which is used by an external user.

Am I truly at risk that an external user could gain the same access as my instance role?

If so, is it worth creating a separate role that *only* has access to `s3:PutObject` in my particular bucket, then assuming that role before generating the presigned post url? That way if compromised somehow it wouldn't have as many privileges as the instance role?

Based on the [Boto3 docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_post), the url should *only* grant access to post a specific object to a specific bucket, but this Macie alert makes me nervous.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to worry about external users gaining access to anything other than uploading files to your bucket.

> htt
>   ps://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/foo.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&
>   X-Amz-Expires=3600&**X-Amz-Credential**=AKIAJRZXXXXXXXXus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Date=20171021T190750Z&X-Amz-Signature=8b84ae9b59e9f8a8d7066ecc39e797c8dc29848abcdef61717

All AWS does is to fetch the **secret_key** associated with your **access_key** (AKIAJRZXXXXXXXX), computes the signature based on object url, expiration time etc., and checks if it matches with the signature in the url. Only you and AWS know the secret_key, no one else does. If the signature matches, the user can upload the file, else access is denied since the URL is tampered with or is past expiration time.